# what is cppcheck architecture and how does it work

Tags: cppcheck

I want to learn about cppCheck architecture - a tool to check cpp sources, but I don't find any document about this. Can you explain about this tool. I read source code but, I is so complicated to understand. Many thanks

I'm expecting that I can know how cppCheck work as well as I can write a document about that architecture

Comment: Have a look here: https://cppcheck.sourceforge.io/manual.pdf , https://sourceforge.net/p/cppcheck/wiki/Home/ and https://linux.die.net/man/1/cppcheck
Basically cppcheck can help you on checking your code for defects. Additionally to the implemented cheks you can write own rules or apply rule sets as addons (e.g. MISRA or CERT)